# Pandas Dataframe Create New Column That is Row Below Current Row's Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I currently have the following sample data frame:

```
No  FlNo    DATE        Loc    
20  1826    6/1/2017    AAA   
20  1112    6/4/2017    BBB   
20  1234    6/6/2017    CCC    
20  43      6/7/2017    DDD    
20  1840    6/8/2017    EEE
```

I want to create a new column called "New Date" that is the next row's date value.  Please see desired output below:

```
No  FlNo    DATE        Loc    New Date   
20  1826    6/1/2017    AAA    6/4/2017   
20  1112    6/4/2017    BBB    6/6/2017
20  1234    6/6/2017    CCC    6/7/2017
20  43      6/7/2017    DDD    6/8/2017 
20  1840    6/8/2017    EEE    NaN
```

After searching stack overflow I'm only able to find code on how to create a new column with the PREVIOUS row's date....not the next row's date.

Comment: Did you take a look at your previous question?

Comment: yes I did ... but I think this current question is distinct from the other one

Comment: Of course, this is a duplicate of `shift`, that is perfectly alright.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand....what do you mean by duplicate of shift?

Comment: `df['New Date'] = df['Date'].shift(-1)`

Comment: oh! that worked!  that is so nifty....thank you very much